# Why dropvalue between <> not supported in ckeditor?

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor

I use this code in the CKEditor File plugin.js to display the value of a dropdown.

```
strings.push(['<<<EmpFname>>>', 'Career Profiles', 'Career Profiles']);
```

But in the browser it only displays `<< >>` Why?
I want it `<<<EmpFname>>>` in browser
What to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That happens because < and > are HTML special characters. You have to use the [HTML code](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm) for each character like this:

```
strings.push(['&lt;&lt;&lt;EmpFname&gt;&gt;&gt;', 'Career Profiles', 'Career Profiles']);
```

The < code is `&lt;` and the > code is `&gt;`.